# Thread 1 EXC error

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've been creating a firebase database but I have one error that I just can't get past. It says:

> thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)'

It's probably something simple that I'm just looking past. Any Ideas?

Here's the code & the error is on the line of code:

```
//
//  Database.swift
//  intern
//
//  Created by Lani  Daniels on 8/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Lani  Daniels. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct PostStruct {
    let title: String
    let message: String
}

class DatabaseViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts: [PostStruct] = []

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1)as! UILabel
        label1.text=posts[indexPath.row].title
```

**// ERROR BELOW:thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)**
            let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2)as! UILabel
            label2.text=posts[indexPath.row].message

```
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift is case sensitive.

Comment: So, I corrected the grammatical error but I ended up getting an error on the line below. it says "thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)" Any idea what this is about?

Comment: it cant crash on both lines... tell us which line it is crashing on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the first error:

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

Change tableview to tableView

For the second one:
It seems like you're trying to access to the outlet that might be not a UILabel. check this by making optional biding like:

```
let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
```

and check that label using breakpoint. It might be nil.

Also it is better to use a custom cell class with two labels as outlets and then dequeue that custom cell in the cellForRowAt method:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
}
```

And then

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell

        cell?.firstLabel.text=posts[indexPath.row].title
        cell?.secondLabel.text=posts[indexPath.row].message

    return cell!
}
```

And don't forget to set that custom class for the cell in the interface builder

Comment: I didn't downvote but this question should be closed as a typo

Comment: So, I corrected the grammatical error but I ended up getting an error on the line below. it says "thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)" Any idea what this is about?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to access to the outlet that might be not a UILabel. check this by making optional biding like: let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel and check that label using breakpoint. It might be nil. Also it is better to use a custom cell class with two labels as outlets and then dequeue that custom cell in the cellForRowAt method